# Global Variable warning from warnings module

Tags: python

Whenever I try to change a variable in Python to global, I get an error message before the code actually runs. The code still runs fine despite these error messages. This is one that I've got:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "N:\Documents\Computer Science\Sample CAB 2\Estimate\Task 2 Estimate.py", line 202
    global loop
SyntaxWarning: name 'loop' is assigned to before global declaration
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is self-explanatory:

`name 'loop' is assigned to before global declaration`

Move the `global` deceleration above the first assignment.

```
a = 1
global a

SyntaxWarning: name 'a' is assigned to before global declaration
  global a
```

Compared to:

```
global a
a = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a global variable before using that inside the program. For your reference, I'm showing you a demo program here.

```
g = 100 #it is global
def func(l):
  print(l) #local value of x
  global g
  print(g) #global value of x
  g = 120
func(10)
print(g)
```

Output Will be,

```
10
100
120
```